# moving a picture box to random X and Y when a timer ticks

Tags: c#

I have this pictureBox called obstaclePicture, which I'd like to move to a new random X and Y position when my timer (obstacleTimer) ticks.

The point with it moving is that it is a obstacle in the game that I've made.

The form's 1025; 545px big.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your picturebox has dimensions of 100x100 px. timer1 should be enabled

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public Random r = new Random();
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int x = r.Next(0,925);
            int y = r.Next(0,445);
            pictureBox1.Top = y;
            pictureBox1.Left = x;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            tm.Interval = 100;
            tm.Tick += new EventHandler(tm_Tick);
            tm.Start();
        }
        Timer tm = new Timer();
        void tm_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pictureBox1.Location = new Point((int)(new Random().Next(0, 1025)), (int)(new Random().Next(0, 545)));
        }

    }
```

**Edited:** You must also check your picture is in or outside form:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            tm.Interval = 1000;
            tm.Tick += new EventHandler(tm_Tick);
            tm.Start();
        }
        Timer tm = new Timer();
        int X = 0;
        int Y = 0;
        void tm_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            X = ((int)(new Random().Next(0, 1025)));
            Y = ((int)(new Random().Next(0, 545)));
            if (X > 1025 - pictureBox1.Width)
            {
                X = 1025 - pictureBox1.Width;
            }
            if (Y > 545 - pictureBox1.Height)
            {
                Y = 545 - pictureBox1.Height;
            }
            pictureBox1.Location = new Point(X, Y);
        }

    }
```